# Proving or disproving the convergence of a sequence

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm looking to determine the convergence of $\{e^{in}\}_{n=1}^\infty$ in $\mathbb{C}$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Using the definition of convergence that iff $\exists \  \epsilon > 0: \forall \  n_0 \in \mathbb{N}, \exists \ n \ge n_0, |z_n - z| \le \epsilon$.

Using $z_n = e^{in} = \cos{n} + i\sin{n}$, and anticipating that the sequence is divergent, I am looking to show a that $|z_n - z| \ge \epsilon$ but I'm not sure how, since $n$ is in radians, not degrees. Thank you in advance for any guidance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that the series converge to $w$. Let $\epsilon=\frac{1}{20}$. Then there is an $N$ such that if $n\ge N$ then $|e^{in}-w|\lt \frac{1}{20}$.

By the Triangle Inequality, if $n\ge N$ then 
$$|e^{i(n+1)}-e^{in}|\le |e^{i(n+1)}-z|+|z-e^{in}|\le \frac{1}{10}.$$
However, $|e^{i(n+1)}-e^{in}|=|e^i-1|=|(\cos 1-1)+i\sin 1|\gt \frac{1}{10}$.

Answer (score 0):

It's divergent. For if $z_n$ was convergent, then so is $\bar{z_n}$; this would imply $z_n + \bar{z_n}$ is convergent, i.e., $2\text{Re}(z_n)$ is convergent. Then $2\cos n$ is convergent, a contradiction.